# Access terminal stdin when it's the source of the bash script itself

Tags: command-line, bash, input, redirect

This is slightly messy to explain.

I have a script that I want to deploy like this:

```
curl -Ls example.com/myscript.sh | bash
```

The trouble is the script reads from standard input like so:

```
echo "You should edit /srv/pillar/tm.sls now. Comments are in the file."
echo Type "skip" to skip or anything else to edit.
read text
if [ "$text" != "skip" ]; then
sudo pico /srv/pillar/tm.sls
fi
```

Now, since stdin is obviously serving as the source of the script itself, this doesn't currently work. Is there a way I can regain the terminal?

(The current workaround is to deploy it like this: `curl -Ls example.com/myscript.sh > myscript.sh && bash myscript.sh`)

Comment: don't force users to use pico. use `editor=${VISUAL:-$EDITOR}; sudo "${editor:-pico}" file`

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I looked for a variable like that, but neither VISUAL nor EDITOR were set. Also didn't know about {$VAR:-default} substitution, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

```
bash <(curl -Ls example.com/myscript.sh)
```

Comment: Thanks - I still don't understand from the Gnu page how that's different from piping, but it does work. It's better than my current workaround, but I was still hoping for a way in the form `curl ... | bash`, because I think that's what people expect.

Comment: @SteveBennett this is different from piping in that this invokes `bash filename` where `filename` is the name of the FIFO to which the `curl` process writes its output. Piping is not possible by definition: it connects a stream to bash's `stdin`.

Comment: Piping has a side-effect: the components of a pipeline are executed in subshells. The difficulty is seen in something like this: `seq 10 | while read num; do ((sum+=num)); done; echo $sum` -- $sum is blank because the while loop is executed in a subshell, and all the modifications to the "sum" variable disappear when the subshell exits.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Interesting that I've never seen this technique before!